# Creating table, copying over field with no data, then copying over data in next fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called mytable that has four fields (id, field2, field3, field4).

I want to make another table called tablecopy that will take components from mytable. In one field I want to copy over JUST the column name and pk constraints from mytable. Then in the other fields of tablecopy I want to copy over 'field2' and 'field3' from mytable (with the data).

Here's what I'm working with.

```
CREATE TABLE mycopy (LIKE mytable INCLUDING ALL);

INSERT INTO mycopy
SELECT field2, field3 FROM mytable;
```

The problem is it field2 is a character varying and it's trying to put that in my id field. I want that field2 in the next column over from id. That id field shouldn't have any data.

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may specify the columns in the `mycopy` table into which you want to insert `field2` and `field3`:

```
INSERT INTO mycopy (field2, field3)
SELECT field2, field3
FROM mytable;
```

This is the preferred way of doing `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` for several reasons.  Even if you got away with not specifying the target columns, later on if the table structure were to change, or someone did a vacuum, the script could suddenly stop working the way you intend.  Also, by explicitly specifying the target columns you make it clear to anyone else who inherits your code.

**Edit:** If you expect Postgres to auto populate the `Id` column in the `mycopy` table, then your table definition should look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mycopy (
    Id  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    field1 TEXT NOT NULL,
    field2 TEXT NOT NULL,
    field3 TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Now Postgres will automatically increment the `Id` column as you insert your data.

Comment: Okay Tim so I should make mycopy with the column names I want, then run this query?

Comment: @Nick Yes, that sounds reasonable to me.  If you get stuck, then edit your question with that information.

Comment: It doesn't work the way I'd like. The Id column is now blank and the field2 and field3 are in mycopy (which is what I wanted). The problem is I can't enter anything into that id column

Comment: The `Id` column _should_ be blank, because you didn't assign any data to it.  Most likely you intend for `Id` to be an auto increment column.

Comment: That did it Tim! Thank you very much. I was trying to figure that out for a while. I knew the Id column was going to be blank but I didn't know I wouldn't be able to type anything into those cells. Your auto increment solved that issue though.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO mycopy
(a_column, other_column)
SELECT field2, field3 FROM mytable;
```

You need to define the column names to be inserted into in the same order as your select statement columns.

Comment: nitsram, wouldn't that put field2 of mytable in the id column of mycopy? I don't want that

Comment: You're right! I've changed it to be more general. Thanks.